# REST convention for handling verb

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js

After watching [intro to sails.js](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GK-tFvpIR7c), I realize that he can create/update a record using a simple GET request with parameters on its url, but what I know is you have to use specific method for specific action, e.g. use POST to create a new record. Is that the correct way to do rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sails.js video is teaching something that is not RESTful. Use the proper HTTP verbs:

- `POST /resources` with body: Create new resource under collection, ID is generated by the server.
- `PUT /resources/{id}` with body: Create new resource with ID supplied by the client
- `GET /resources`: Get a list of all resources
- `GET /resources/{id}`: Get one resource
- `DELETE /resources/{id)`: Delete one resource

Answer (score 0):

The REST conventions are somewhat disputed, however most people use the rails style for their urls.  Here is an example:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: URLs are not related to HTTP verbs.